# Updating document in firestore causes infinite loop

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So I am trying to update a document in `firestore` and I do this in a `.forEach`and when I execute the update it causes an infinite loop. Can someone look at my code and tell me how to stop this? I figure it would just run one time since the snapshot size is only 1.

```
this.categoriesCollection.ref.where('name', '==', 
  transaction.category.toLowerCase()).limit(1).onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => 
    {
      if (querySnapshot.size == 1) {
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          this.categoriesCollection.doc(doc.id)
            .update({totalSpent: doc.data().totalSpent + transaction.amount});
        });
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're adding a listener to search query that returns one document, then you're making changes to that document.  When that document is changed, the results of the query change, and your listener is invoked again with the new results, which means it's going to update yet another document, which means that the query changes.  Etc, etc.

If you just want to update a document from a query, don't use `onSnapshot()` for that.  Just use `get()` to obtain the search results a single time, then update the documents from the results it gives you.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out all I had to do is set the whole thing equal to a variable and then at the end of the closure just call `unsubscribe();` and that stopped the loop. So my code is now:

```
let unsubscribe = this.categoriesCollection.ref.where('name', '==', transaction.category.toLowerCase()).limit(1).onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
  if (querySnapshot.size == 1) {
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      this.categoriesCollection.doc(doc.id).update({totalSpent: doc.data().totalSpent + transaction.amount});
    });
  }
});
unsubscribe();
```

Comment: I think using get() in my answer is a better option.  It looks like you don't really need a subscriptions, just a single set of results a single time.